# How to run powershell scriptblock as domain user?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have a script block that I'm trying to make it run as a different domain user.

```
$Username = 'domain\test'
$Password = '1234'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName,$pass

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{
write-host "hello"

} -Credential $cred -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

When I run it I got the following error:

```
[test-pc] Connecting to remote server test-pc failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests.
 Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM se
rvice: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Why the script is trying to authenticate locally and not against the DC ?
Thanks

Comment: Is the WS-Management service running on the remote computer? If you're trying to use PowerShell remoting it needs to be enabled and the correct ports need to be open. I don't think you're even being authenticated yet.

Comment: Have you setup WinRM on the remote server to accept WinRM?
Have you been through the steps in about_Remote_Troubleshooting ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6

Comment: I have a lab with a Windows 10 client and a DC (2012 R2). When I execute my script on the client , I want to use another domain account.

Comment: The error message tells you what you need to do. Go on your 2012 R2 box, open PowerShell as admin and type in `winrm quickconfig`

Comment: Is it possible to another method without altering the DC configuration ?

Comment: [Here is an article from MS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699046.aspx) that goes into the limitations of what you can do without the WinRM service running.

Comment: I just want to execute the command on the windows 10 client , not on the DC as another user. Is WinRM still needed ?

Comment: If you are needing to execute a remote command (from one machine to another), you will need to have WinRM service configured / running. If it is a local command, no.

Comment: The only thing that is going to happen remotly is the authentication with the DC. the write-host hello is executed locally on the windows 10 box.

Comment: Why not just `run as` your powershell session ? Your script is trying execute remotely to your local machine. In that case, you would need to configure WinRm on that windows 10 box.  What is the need to run as another user if you are just doing `Write-Host` ?

Comment: I don't to use run as since it will ask the user for credentials. The script is going to be pushed as logn script and it need to use a special AD account to run some commands .I put Write-host the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Without knowing what the **actual** script is attempting to accomplish, it is very difficult to assist you with your issue or, provide you with a direction with command. When a PowerShell script is executed, it is generally executed by the current user, unless specified. There are several commands that accept  `-Credential` . However, in this example you are attempting to execute remotely to the local machine. In this instance, you would need to enable WinRM. The reason why `Write-Host` does not take `-Credential` is because there is no special permissions needed.

Comment: I want to execute manage-bde with a specific domain user. That is my objective. All the commands are going to be executed locally , th eonly thing that happens remotely is the authentication with the AD.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't actually want to run the script remotely, you can use `Start-Process` to run Powershell *as* another user, which will then execute your command/script as that user.

(See [powershell command line help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for full syntax options and examples)

```
# Using Get-Credential to illustrate, substitute with your own credential code
$cred = Get-Credential

# Run Command:
Start-Process -FilePath Powershell -Credential $cred -ArgumentList '-Command', 'Write-Host "Hello"'

# Run Script:    
Start-Process -FilePath Powershell -Credential $cred -ArgumentList '-File', 'C:\folder\script.ps1'
```

Comment: is it possible to use it with a scriptblock ?

Comment: Yes, `-Command` accepts a scriptblock, see the link I included as it covers this.

Comment: @Nae How nice of MS to not redirect the original url, I've now updated it.